# Split a members of Dictionary in python

Tags: python

How can I store a Dictionary input in a Collection
like:
all inputs are given at once
terminal input:

```
Apple 1, Orange 2, Banana 3
```

Store in Collection:

```
{"Apple": 1, "Orange": 2, "Banana": 3}
```

Comment: Split on comma initially then split those tokens on whitespace

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your string initially on comma to get the key/value pairs.

Then, for each pair, split on whitespace.

Build the dictionary as follows:

```
input_value = 'Apple 1, Orange 2, Banana 3'

d = {}

for e in input_value.split(','):
    key, value = e.split()
    d[key] = int(value)

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Apple': 1, 'Orange': 2, 'Banana': 3}
```

**Note:**

This can be done in one line but that only serves to obfuscate the code. Simple steps like this are easy to understand and maintain and can be more efficient.

For those who like one-liners:

```
d = {key: int(value) for key, value in map(str.split, input_value.split(','))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting input like `"Apple 1, Orange 2, Banana 3"`, you can split this in stages:

```py
x = 'Apple 1, Orange 2, Banana 3'

# Split into a list of strings separated on ', '
y = x.split(', ')

# y contains ['Apple 1', 'Orange 2', 'Banana 3']

# Split each of the separate strings into two strings on ' ' 
z = [a.split(' ') for a in y]

# z contains [['Apple', '1'], ['Orange', '2'], ['Banana', '3']]

# Finally, take the list of lists and turn it into a dictionary
print({k: int(v) for k, v in z})

Out[16]: {'Apple': 1, 'Orange': 2, 'Banana': 3}
```

I should note that this is likely to be a fairly error-prone way of receiving input as it relies entirely on someone inputting  a string exactly in the specified format, which seems unlikely...

All of the above could also be combined into a single line of code which would more memory-efficient.

```py
{k: int(v) for k, v in (a.split(' ') for a in x.split(', '))}
```